# FutureBuilder doesn't update when updating the database

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

I was working in a simple notes app in flutter, this is my code.

i just made this example to preview the problem

This is the home page that navigate to a create page, and uses a futureBuilder to display the data from the database

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_test/db.dart';
import 'create.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  Future futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureData = _getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _getData() async{
    return await db.queryAllRows('notes');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _navigateToCreatePage(context),
      ),

      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['title']),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          
          return Text('Empty');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _navigateToCreatePage(context) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreatePage())
  );
}
```

and this is the create page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:futurebuilder_test/db.dart';

class CreatePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  final TextEditingController title = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController description = TextEditingController();

  void save(context) async {
    await db.insert(
      'notes', {'title': title.text, 'description': description.text}
    );
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
              controller: title,
            ),

            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
              controller: description,
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () => save(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when the user click the save button it adds a new note to the database and pop the page back to home screen *It's supposed* that the future builder update it's data after submitting new data to the database
but this is not happening. could someone help me.

Comment: because it was working fine, but after i updated flutter to 1.22.2 it just stopped, there is youtube videos that is working fine in it

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose the previous page using [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html) or handle everything with [state management](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjy582mzczsAhXysaQKHa1_AbMQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fsuper-declarative%2Funderstanding-state-management-and-why-you-never-will-dd84b624d0e&usg=AOvVaw2ya0_qfUn131S0FzMraI4P).